# IIS7 SSL certificate installation: cannot find the certificate request associated with this certificate file

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

[KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/959216) say this error is from bug in IIS when trying to search for the file; it "does not know how to retrieve the friendly name of a certificate in a PKCS#7 file."

The recommended workaround is to open the Certificates Snap-in in MMC and assign a friendly  name.

I've done that, and am still getting the error.  Would be grateful for the solution. Thanks

Comment: You need to install the response on the same machine where the request was generated.

Comment: That is indeed the case here. The request was generated on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

I has this exact problem, the zip file from my certificate vendor included multiple different certificate files.  I wrongly thought that any of them would do, but actually there is only 1 specific one that you must use and I was using the wrong one.